# Global symbol requires explicit package name perl

Tags: perl

This code is giving me a Global Symbol requires explicit package name error. It's throwing it on the second time $user is defined. Below the code is the error. I don't understand the reasoning behind $user not having one. I'm trying to add to the hash that's returned.

```
my $self     = shift;
my %json     = ('err' => 0, 'msg' => '');
my $user     = Order2016::get_orders($self->usernum); # Returns Hash

# Query to grab session history data
my $sql     = "select rate.duration, rate.price, rate.description, rate.active, order.user_id, order.quantity, order.add_date, order.modify_date, order.end_date, order.last_bill, order.next_bill, item.*
            from rate, order, item
            where order.user_id = ?
            and order.rate_id = rate.id
            and rate.item_id = item.id";
my $query   = new SQL($sql, $self->usernum);
my $hist    = $query->GetRecordsAsHashRef();

$user{'uid'} = $self->usernum;

$self->Print(to_json($user));
```

Global symbol "%user" requires explicit package name at /devroot/depot/wxtap/deploy/scripts//Account.pm line 1340.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/Apache2/porting.pm line 90.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that `$user` is a hash *reference*, not a hash. To use it, you need to dereference it first (using the `->` operator):

```
$user->{uid} = $self->usernum;
```

This could also be written as:

```
$$user{uid} = ...;
```

...but that's far less common, and it's much more idiomatic to use the former method.

Comment: That was it. I appreciate it. I come from a PHP background.

Answer (score 1):

Please try $user->{'uid'}.
$user is being used as a reference here.